# How can I configure AWS ALB to return GRPC INTERNAL error when backend GRPC service is down?

Tags: grpc, aws-application-load-balancer

We are running GRPC services behind a ALB

When all of the backend nodes went down, client will get a standard HTTP 503 error response from the ALB

We would like to make sure our client get error code in GRPC format
like the Code: "INTERNAL" in here
https://grpc.github.io/grpc/core/md_doc_statuscodes.html
even if all our backend service is down

Is there any way we can achive that?

I have looked into some solutions proposed in other stackoverflow posts such as DNS failver or putting a cloudfront in front of it. Wondering if there's any easier solution or ALB config I'm missing